# Python- how to use while loop to return longest line of code

Tags: python, loops, max

I just started learning python 3 weeks ago, I apologize if this is really basic. I needed to open a .txt file and print the length of the longest line of code in the file. I just made a random file named it myfile and saved it to my desktop.

```
myfile= open('myfile', 'r')
line= myfile.readlines()
len(max(line))-1 
#the (the "-1" is to remove the /n)
```

Is this code correct? I put it in interpreter and it seemed to work OK.

But I got it wrong because apparently I was supposed to use a while loop. Now I am trying to figure out how to put it in a while loop. I've read what it says on python.org, watched videos on youtube and looked through this site. I just am not getting it. The example  to follow that was given is this:

```
import os
du=os.popen('du/urs/local')
while 1:
   line= du.readline()
   if not line:
        break
   if list(line).count('/')==3:
         print line,
```

Comment: Your first approach was fine. You were sorting by the sort order of the lines, which orders them in alphabetical order. Using `max(lines, key=len)` runs `len()` on each line and uses that to sort the actual lines, which is what you want.

Comment: `max(line)` finds the "maximal" string in a list. By default, the strings are compared alphabetically and not according to their length. `'z' > 'abc'`.

Comment: thanks for all the feed back and helpful details. it's really appreciated! yea sorry if the actual question part wasn't clear. i was asking 1) if my code was correct (instructor didn't give any feedback) and 2) how to use the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking what you have and stripping out the parts you don't need

```
myfile = open('myfile', 'r')
max_len = 0
while 1:
    line = myfile.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if len(line) # ... somethin
        # something
```

Note that this is a crappy way to loop over a file. It relys on the file having an empty line at the end. But homework is homework...

Comment: Thank you. This really helps. And dually noted that is a crappy way to loop over a file.

Answer (score 3):

```
print max([len(line) for line in file(filename).readlines()])
```

Comment: The `key` argument is there for a reason, so why not use it? Also, `file` doesn't exist in Python3.

Comment: sure, sure, see the smiley :)

Comment: @Blender But then you have to apply len to it afterwards... seems like doing more work than necessary!

Comment: `max(imap(len, open(filename, 'r'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
max(['b','aaa']) is 'b'
```

This lexicographic order isn't what you want to maximise, you can use the `key` flag to choose a different function to maximise, like `len`.

```
max(['b','aaa'], key=len) is 'aaa'
```

So the solution could be: `len ( max(['b','aaa'], key=len) is 'aaa' )`.

A more elegant solution would be to use list comprehension:

```
max ( len(line)-1 for line in myfile.readlines() )
```

.

As an aside you should enclose opening a file using a with statement, this will worry about closing the file after the indentation block:

```
with open('myfile', 'r') as mf:
    print max ( len(line)-1 for line in mf.readlines() )
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's have mentioned, you need to find the line with the maximum length, which mean giving the `max()` function a `key=` argument to extract that from each of lines in the list you pass it.

Likewise, in a while loop you'd need to read each line and see if its length was greater that the longest one you had seen so far, which you could store in a separate variable and initialize to 0 before the loop.

BTW, you would not want to open the file with `os.popen()` as shown in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to understand if we keep it simple:

```
max_len = -1 # Nothing was read so far
with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:   # Opens the file and magically closes at the end
  for line in f:
    max_len = max(max_len, len(line))
print max_len
```

As this is homework... I would ask myself if I should count the line feed character or not. If you need to chop the last char, change len(line) by len(line[:-1]).

If you have to use while, try this:

```
max_len = -1 # Nothing was read
with open("t.txt", "r") as f:   # Opens the file
   while True:
      line = f.readline()
      if(len(line)==0):
         break
      max_len = max(max_len, len(line[:-1]))
print max_len
```

Answer (score 0):

For those still in need. This is a little function which does what you need:

```
def get_longest_line(filename):
    length_lines_list = []
    open_file_name = open(filename, "r") 
    all_text = open_file_name.readlines()
    for line in all_text:
        length_lines_list.append(len(line))
    max_length_line = max(length_lines_list)
    for line in all_text:
        if len(line) == max_length_line:
            return line.strip()
    open_file_name.close()
```